# Wordpress Tags Error/Issue

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress - and there is a way to publish pages and posts.

I am creating Posts  and for that you can add tags (which just give you more keywords to rank for it shows up at the bottom of the posts - wordpress creates pages with these tags and it ranks for the tags in the search engines)

I created all these links inside the posts - and now after checking the 
links they are fine on the main post page but for all the tags which come with that posts - the actual links get screwed up by wordpress bc they add a /tag/ before 
the link.

This is the URL which gets created thats comes with the posts.

Example :-http://www.sitename.com/**tag**/tagname/

Please help

Comment: I created all these links inside the posts - and now after checking the links they are fine on the main post(http://www.sitename.com/tag/tagname/) page but for all the tags which come with that posts - the actual links get screwed up by wordpress bc they add a /tag/ before the link (http://www.sitename.com/tag/tagname/)This doesnt work on the sub pages

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify if you have in the used theme the tag.php file, if not, then use one, for reference check the one from "Twentyeleven" WordPress template. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates)
2. In your dashboard, Settings > Permalinks, set to "Default", then save, then check "Post name" and save it again.

Good luck! :)